# How far from a specific state in a Markov chain

Tags: statistics

Problem:
Lets say we have an irreducible Markov chain.
Given a failure state or non desirable state F and a current state S
Is it possible to find how far we are from the failure state F.

Example: if we try to model an engine failure using Markov process and using historic data we have a state transition matrix P, one of which is a state where the engine was failed .
Now , in a dynamic system, if the current state S and a state transition matrix are given, can we calculate how far we are from failure state F.

Mathematically:

x(n+1) = (x)P^n

Right hand side of the equation gives us a vector v which consists of probabilities of transitioning to different states at stage n.
With different value of n, the values in this vector v will change
one of the values in v will be the probability of going to state F.
I want to find for what n , transitioning probability to F is maximum.

Comment: (This question belongs to math.stackexchange..) You can get an approximate solution by simply computing your probability for all n for which L1 distance between x P^n and the stationary distribution x* is more than epsilon. This assumes your chain is also aperiodic.